# ImageMagick convert .jpg to .ico while using stdout as output channel

Tags: imagemagick, base64, stdout, favicon

I want to use ImageMagick to generate a multiple sizes icon file from a jpeg image. The following command works well:

```
convert image.jpg -define icon:auto-resize=64,48,32,16 favicon.ico.
```

Furthermore, I would like to use stdout as output channel so I tried ([Cf documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#fd)):

```
convert image.jpg -define icon:auto-resize=64,48,32,16 ico:fd:1
```

But it does not produce any result.

What would be the correct command to generate multiple size icon and use stdout as output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for stdout? Then this would work

```
convert image.jpg -define icon:auto-resize=64,48,32,16 ico:-
```

Comment: this is it ! do you have any clue why my command using `ico:fd:1` was not working ? The two commands are supposed to be equivalent. I am using ImageMagick 6.9.0-10 on OS X.